# How to fix Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) in HTTP POST to get an token using the authorization code

Tags: angular, linkedin-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using the **Linkedin** **Authorization Code Flow** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow) to request permission from the member and get their token, but I have issues with https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken request/response. How can i get the token?

When I try to get the token using the authorization code in a HTTP POST request with a Content-Type header of x-www-form-urlencoded, I get **`Http status 0 and Unknown Error.`**

```
getLinkedinToken(code): Observable<any> {

let data = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/login&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET";

return this.http.post(`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`,
data, { 
 headers: new HttpHeaders()
 .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
 .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
})
.pipe(map(res =>  res), catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));

}
```

A successful access token request returns a JSON object containing the following fields: access_token, expire_in. But I get `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error` in console.

Also a warning **CORB** message `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response MY URL with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details`